# C Removing Newlines in a Portable and International Friendly Way

Tags: c, parsing, localization

Simple question here with a potentially tricky answer:  I am looking for a **portable** and **localization friendly** way to remove trailing newlines in C, preferably something standards-based.

I am already aware of the following solutions:

- Parsing for some combination of `\r` and `\n`.  Really not pretty when dealing with Windows, *nix and Mac, all which use different sequences to represent a new line.  Also, do other languages even use the same escape sequence for a new line?  I expect this will blow up in languages that use different glyphs from English (say, Japanese or the like).
- Removing trailing `n` bytes and replacing final `\0`.  Seems like a more brittle way of doing the above.
- `isspace` looks tempting but I need to only match newlines.  Other whitespace is considered valid token text.
- C++ has a class to do this but it is of little help to me in a pure-C world.
- `locale.h` seems like what I am after but I cannot see anything pertinent to extracting newline tokens.

So, with that, is this an instance that I will have to "roll my own" functionality or is there something that I have missed?  Thanks!

---

**Solution**

I ended up combining both answers from `Weather Vane` and `Loic`, respectively, for my final solution.  What worked was to use the handy `strcspn` function to break on the first newline character as selected from Loic's provided links.  Thus, I can select delimiters based on a number of supported locales.  Is a good point that there are too many to support generically at this level; I didn't even know that there were several competing encodings for the Cyrillic.

In this way, I can achieve "good enough" multinational support while still using standard library functions.

Since I can only accept one answer, I am selecting Weather Vane's as his was the final invocation I used.  That being said, it was really the two answers together that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best one I know is

```
buffer [ strcspn(buffer, "\r\n") ] = 0;
```

which is a safe way of dealing with all the combinations of `\r` and `\n` - both, one or none.

Comment: Spiffy, didn't know about `strcspn`.  How does it handle foreign locales?

Comment: The MS documentation for `strcspn` mentions locale, perhaps you can follow it up. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe8sk0x7.aspx

Comment: Ah, was looking at the Posix version which does not include the locale parameter (at least the one from `string.h` doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to replace one or more whitespace characters with one standard space (US-ASCII 0x20). Considering only ISO-8859-1 characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), whitespace consists of any byte in 0x00..0x20 (C0 control characters and space) and 0x7F..0xA0 (delete, C1 control characters and no-break space). Notice that US-ASCII is subset of ISO-8859-1.

But take into account that Windows 1251 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) assign different, visible (non-control) characters to the range 0x80..0x9F. In this case, those bytes cannot be replaced by spaces without lost of textual information.

Resources for an extensive definition of whitespace characters:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#Whitespace
- http://unicode.org/reports/tr23/
- http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/charts/CodeCharts.pdf

Take also onto account that different encodings may be used, most commonly:

- ISO-8859-1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
- UTF-8 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
- Windows 1251 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)

But in non-western countries (for instance Russia, Japan), further character encodings are also usual. Numerous encodings exist, but it probably does not make sense to try to support each and every known encoding.

Thus try to define and restrict your use-cases, because implementing it in full generality means a lot of work.

Comment: Reading the comment, you are recommending replacing `CR` and `LF` with spaces.  That will not be useful for content which is delimited by *newlines* no matter what encoding is used.

Comment: I apologize if I misunderstood you (Thomas Dickey), but `CR` and `LF` *are* newlines; according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode, the ranges I suggested cover all newlines of ISO-8859-1 (and also further control characters). But of course, the general idea has to be refined according to the particular requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for C++ users with the same problem.

Matching a newline character for any locale and character type can be done like this:

```
#include <locale>

template<class Char>
bool is_newline(Char c, std::locale const & loc = std::locale()) 
{
  // Translate character into default locale and character type.
  // Then, test against '\n', which is the only newline character there.
  return std::use_facet< std::ctype<Char>>(loc).narrow(c, ' ') == '\n';
}
```

Now, removing all trailing newlines can be done like this:

```
void remove_trailing_newlines(std::string & str) {
  while (!str.empty() && is_newline(*str.rbegin())
    str.pop_back();
}
```

This should be absolutely portable, as it relies only on standard C++ functions.